# Selectively including columns based on a "closest value" test

Tags: r, dataframe, closest

I have a df that looks like:

```
SNP        FRQ     ACB     ASW      BEB     CDX     ACB_alt ASW_alt BEB_alt CDX_alt P         EFF
rs10007883 0.3588  0.53645 0.54918  0.19186 0.10752 0.46354 0.45081 0.80813 0.89247 0.013510  -0.000152
rs10009522 0.8654  0.60416 0.47540  0.16279 0.14516 0.39583 0.52459 0.83720 0.85483 0.019823  0.009342
rs10010325 0.5277  0.45833 0.467213 0.45348 0.58602 0.54166 0.53278 0.54651 0.41397 0.9182352 -0.09135
rs10010809 0.3958  0.375   0.401639 0.29069 0.15591 0.62500 0.59836 0.70930 0.84408 0.0001923 -0.09402
rs10015151 0.6939  0.57291 0.44262  0.54651 0.36559 0.42708 0.55737 0.45348 0.63440 0.0192341 0.00012
rs10016978 0.5633  0.5625  0.56557  0.42441 0.16666 0.43750 0.43442 0.57558 0.83333 0.0153223 -0.00543
```

I would like to make a new data frame that is conditionally constructed based on a "closer to" test. I want to test to see if the FRQ column is closer to the ACB column or the ACB_alt column. If the FRQ is closer to the ACB column, I want the columns "SNP, FRQ, ACB, ASW, BEB, and CDX" to be kept in the new data.frame. If the FRQ column is closer to ACB_alt, I want the columns "SNP, FRQ, ACB_alt,ASW_alt, BEB_alt, and CDX_alt" to be kept in the new data frame. However,I want the names of the new columns in the new dataframe to remain "ACB, ASW,BEB,and CDX" even if I am using the alt values.

Let's run through the first two lines as an example. The FRQ in line 1 is 0.3588. and since 0.3588 is closer to ACB_alt (0.46354) than ACB (0.53645), I want the first line of the new data frame to be made from the alternative values:

```
SNP        FRQ    ACB     ASW     BEB     CDX
rs10007883 0.3588 0.46354 0.45081 0.80813 0.89247
```

The FRQ in line 2 is 0.8654. and since 0.8654 is closer to ACB (0.60416) than ACB_alt (0.39583), I want the second line of the new data frame to be made from the regular values:

```
SNP        FRQ    ACB     ASW     BEB     CDX
rs10007883 0.3588 0.46354 0.45081 0.80813 0.89247
rs10009522 0.8654 0.60416 0.47540 0.16279 0.14516
```

Can anyone help me with this?

EDIT:: I added a column named "EFF" that I have. If I use the normal values, I want EFF to remain the same. If I use the alternative values, I want EFF to have it's sign flipped.

Comment: How will you like to handle cases when both `ACB_alt` and `ACB` are equidistant from `FRQ`?

Comment: My actual data file goes to the millionths place so I don't think I'll run into that, because my FRQ file only goes to the tens-thousandths place. That's great thinking though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paul's code uses a better approach than what I scrapped (I've never heard of *filter* until now :/), but I thought it was worth to post. I did it naively, essentially looping through every row and appending the result to an empty data frame.

EDIT: I've included the "EFF" column as requested and the function now flips the sign for the alternative case.

```
library('tidyverse')

df <- read_table2("SNP        FRQ     ACB     ASW      BEB     CDX     ACB_alt ASW_alt BEB_alt CDX_alt EFF
                  rs10007883 0.3588  0.53645 0.54918  0.19186 0.10752 0.46354 0.45081 0.80813 0.89247 1
                  rs10009522 0.8654  0.60416 0.47540  0.16279 0.14516 0.39583 0.52459 0.83720 0.85483 1
                  rs10010325 0.5277  0.45833 0.467213 0.45348 0.58602 0.54166 0.53278 0.54651 0.41397 1
                  rs10010809 0.3958  0.375   0.401639 0.29069 0.15591 0.62500 0.59836 0.70930 0.84408 1
                  rs10015151 0.6939  0.57291 0.44262  0.54651 0.36559 0.42708 0.55737 0.45348 0.63440 1
                  rs10016978 0.5633  0.5625  0.56557  0.42441 0.16666 0.43750 0.43442 0.57558 0.83333 1")

new_df <- data.frame(SNP=as.character(), FRQ=as.numeric(), ACB=as.numeric(), 
                     ASW=as.numeric(), BEB=as.numeric(), CDX=as.numeric(), 
                     EFF=as.numeric())

compareValues <- function(row){
  if(abs(row$FRQ[1]-row$ACB[1]) <= abs(row$FRQ[1]-row$ACB_alt[1])) {
    row <- row[,colnames(new_df)]
    new_df <<- rbind(new_df, row)
  } else {
    row <- row[,c("SNP", "FRQ", "ACB_alt", "ASW_alt", "BEB_alt", "CDX_alt", "EFF")]
    row$EFF <- -1 * row$EFF  # Negate EFF
    colnames(row) <- colnames(new_df)
    new_df <<- rbind(new_df, row)
  }
}

# Iterate thru rows of df
by(df, 1:nrow(df), compareValues)

print(new_df)
# A tibble: 6 x 7
# SNP          FRQ   ACB   ASW   BEB   CDX   EFF
# <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 rs10007883 0.359 0.464 0.451 0.808 0.892 -1.00
# 2 rs10009522 0.865 0.604 0.475 0.163 0.145  1.00
# 3 rs10010325 0.528 0.542 0.533 0.547 0.414 -1.00
# 4 rs10010809 0.396 0.375 0.402 0.291 0.156  1.00
# 5 rs10015151 0.694 0.573 0.443 0.547 0.366  1.00
# 6 rs10016978 0.563 0.562 0.566 0.424 0.167  1.00
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can you take a look at my edit to see if you can work that into your loop?

Comment: Thanks man! The command by(df,1:nrow(df),compareValues) is spitting out an enormous amount of data (my actual data file is over 5,000 lines long). Is there a way to just store the new data as a variable?

Comment: Do you mean to store the output in memory? _by()_ produces a list, so you can assign the final entry of the list to a variable: `output <- by(df, 1:nrow(df), compareValues)[nrow(df)]` should work if you really want to hide R's data output. But the final output is being stored in _new_df_ anyways, so it's probably overkill.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a "normal" data frame and an "alt" data frame by filtering the rows and renaming the columns. Then just `row_bind` the two data frames together.

We add a `rownames` column at the beginning so we can keep the same row order at the end.

```
library('tidyverse')

df <- read_table2("SNP        FRQ     ACB     ASW      BEB     CDX     ACB_alt ASW_alt BEB_alt CDX_alt
rs10007883 0.3588  0.53645 0.54918  0.19186 0.10752 0.46354 0.45081 0.80813 0.89247
rs10009522 0.8654  0.60416 0.47540  0.16279 0.14516 0.39583 0.52459 0.83720 0.85483
rs10010325 0.5277  0.45833 0.467213 0.45348 0.58602 0.54166 0.53278 0.54651 0.41397
rs10010809 0.3958  0.375   0.401639 0.29069 0.15591 0.62500 0.59836 0.70930 0.84408
rs10015151 0.6939  0.57291 0.44262  0.54651 0.36559 0.42708 0.55737 0.45348 0.63440
rs10016978 0.5633  0.5625  0.56557  0.42441 0.16666 0.43750 0.43442 0.57558 0.83333"
)

df <- add_rownames(df)

df_non_alt <- df %>%
  filter(abs(FRQ - ACB) <= abs(FRQ - ACB_alt)) %>%
  select(-ends_with('_alt'))
df_non_alt
#> # A tibble: 4 x 7
#>   rowname        SNP    FRQ     ACB      ASW     BEB     CDX
#>     <chr>      <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1       2 rs10009522 0.8654 0.60416 0.475400 0.16279 0.14516
#> 2       4 rs10010809 0.3958 0.37500 0.401639 0.29069 0.15591
#> 3       5 rs10015151 0.6939 0.57291 0.442620 0.54651 0.36559
#> 4       6 rs10016978 0.5633 0.56250 0.565570 0.42441 0.16666

df_alt <- df %>%
  filter(abs(FRQ - ACB) > abs(FRQ - ACB_alt)) %>%
  select(rowname, SNP, FRQ, ends_with('_alt')) %>%
  rename_all(~gsub('_alt', '', .))
df_alt
#> # A tibble: 2 x 7
#>   rowname        SNP    FRQ     ACB     ASW     BEB     CDX
#>     <chr>      <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1       1 rs10007883 0.3588 0.46354 0.45081 0.80813 0.89247
#> 2       3 rs10010325 0.5277 0.54166 0.53278 0.54651 0.41397

bind_rows(df_non_alt, df_alt) %>%
  arrange(rowname) %>%
  select(-rowname)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#>          SNP    FRQ     ACB      ASW     BEB     CDX
#>        <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 rs10007883 0.3588 0.46354 0.450810 0.80813 0.89247
#> 2 rs10009522 0.8654 0.60416 0.475400 0.16279 0.14516
#> 3 rs10010325 0.5277 0.54166 0.532780 0.54651 0.41397
#> 4 rs10010809 0.3958 0.37500 0.401639 0.29069 0.15591
#> 5 rs10015151 0.6939 0.57291 0.442620 0.54651 0.36559
#> 6 rs10016978 0.5633 0.56250 0.565570 0.42441 0.16666
```

Comment: Good approach. I would have liked to retain the original order of data.

Comment: When I use the `add_rownames` I get the warning message: `Warning message:
Deprecated, use tibble::rownames_to_column() instead.`

Comment: @Paul. I also have a few columns that aren't listed in this example that are getting lost in your script. I have editted my question to throw in some columns I would like to keep

Answer (score 1):

The another way of solving this with using 'data.table`package. The use of`data.table` in simplest form to solve this would be:

```
library(data.table)
df <- read.table(text = "SNP        FRQ     ACB     ASW      BEB     CDX     ACB_alt ASW_alt BEB_alt CDX_alt
                  rs10007883 0.3588  0.53645 0.54918  0.19186 0.10752 0.46354 0.45081 0.80813 0.89247
                  rs10009522 0.8654  0.60416 0.47540  0.16279 0.14516 0.39583 0.52459 0.83720 0.85483
                  rs10010325 0.5277  0.45833 0.467213 0.45348 0.58602 0.54166 0.53278 0.54651 0.41397
                  rs10010809 0.3958  0.375   0.401639 0.29069 0.15591 0.62500 0.59836 0.70930 0.84408
                  rs10016978 0.5633  0.5625  0.56557  0.42441 0.16666 0.43750 0.43442 0.57558 0.83333", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


dt <- data.table(df)

dt[, .(SNP = SNP,
       FRQ = FRQ, 
       ACB = ifelse(abs(FRQ - ACB) <= abs(FRQ - ACB_alt), ACB, ACB_alt ),
       ASW = ifelse(abs(FRQ - ACB) <= abs(FRQ - ACB_alt), ASW, ASW_alt ),
       BEB = ifelse(abs(FRQ - ACB) <= abs(FRQ - ACB_alt), BEB, BEB_alt ),
       CDX = ifelse(abs(FRQ - ACB) <= abs(FRQ - ACB_alt), CDX, CDX_alt ))]

#Result:
#          SNP    FRQ     ACB      ASW     BEB     CDX
#1: rs10007883 0.3588 0.46354 0.450810 0.80813 0.89247
#2: rs10009522 0.8654 0.60416 0.475400 0.16279 0.14516
#3: rs10010325 0.5277 0.54166 0.532780 0.54651 0.41397
#4: rs10010809 0.3958 0.37500 0.401639 0.29069 0.15591
#5: rs10016978 0.5633 0.56250 0.565570 0.42441 0.16666
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! This is great, but in practice, I have about 30 columns (15 normal, and 15 alt). Though I'm fine with long coding it, is there a way for you to look at my edit and incorporate that?